# Svg sprite from Illustrator (with separate viewBox for each element)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, artboard, sprite

Is there a way to export an .svg sprite directly from Illustrator, with a separate viewBox for each element?

I am only able get one viewBox for the whole set of icons, even when each of them is on its own artboard.

Comment: is it even possible to have multiple viewBoxes per svg file?

Comment: You could always use the Export For Screens option to export each artboard as its own SVG

Comment: @Luciano turns out it is! (I posted the answer below.)

Answer (score 4):

I seem to have found the solution - each sprite element must be converted to a symbol. That creates a viewBox for each symbol when exporting the svg.

An example:

```
<symbol id="badminton" data-name="badminton" viewBox="0 0 33.84 40.41">
```